# ActiveMQ Error in CF9 to CF11 Migration

Tags: coldfusion, activemq-classic

Please forgive me since I'm rather new to this, but I'll try to explain the situation as best as I can.

The current system is running on ColdFusion 9 and ActiveMQ 5.3.1.  We are trying to upgrade the system to ColdFusion 11 and I'm running into some issues.  In ColdFusion 9 ActiveMQ appears to run fine on Beta and Production (we also have a local and alpha environment) however in ColdFusion 11 I get the following error: http://puu.sh/gVp1L/d77453416f.png  This happens in the /CFIDE/adminapi/eventgateway.cfc:204 which of course is a file that has been abstracted to not be readable.

I have tried the following:

- Three different ActiveMQ servers
- Two different installs of CF11
- Going step by step through the eventgateway api

When I manually try to start the Gateway Instance in CFIDE, it goes to a white page, and nothing shows up in the eventgateway log.  The only error I've managed to see was actually in CF9 and it was:

> Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory

I'm assuming that's just a goofy ActiveMQ install locally though.  I did some googling on this error and it says that I might be missing a .jar file within ActiveMQ, but when I view the /lib directory I can see the file they claim must be missing.  Within CF9, I can actually see errors in the eventgateway log, but like I said, I get a white screen and nothing happens in CF11.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the activemq.jar not being including in the cfusion/lib folder for CF11, but was for CF9.